# Morita equivalence for graded von Neumann algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, morita-equivalence

I am interested in understanding Morita equivalence of $Z_2$-graded von Neumann algebras. In the ungraded case, Rieffel showed that all Type I factors are Morita-equivalent, while for Type III factors Morita-equivalence is the same as isomorphism. I would like to know the graded version of these results.  In the graded case it is natural to define a factor as a von Neumann algebra whose super-center consists of scalars. It would also be interesting to know a G-equivariant version, where G is a finite group.